# jquery wait on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery I built a dynamic form; when the first select-input (named `category`) changes a second select-input (named `subcategory`) appears with sub-select items. And this works perfect now.

When a specific url parameter is given I want to auto-fill in the form after the page is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize defaults
    var category = getUrlParameter('category');
    var subcategory = getUrlParameter('subcategory');
    if (category && subcategory) {
        $("select#category").val(category).change();
        $("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
    }
});
```

Where `getUrlParameter` is a helper function I copied from [Sameer Kazi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21903119/5316326).

Currently the first select-input is filled in, the second select-input is generated but not filled in. So actually, the change command needs to wait untill the first change command is ready.

Comment: Did you thought about a bool value switching true on `$("select#category").val(category).change();`

Comment: *when the first select-input (named category) changes a second select-input (named subcategory) appears with sub-select items* we need that code, its important for the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can using jQuery's [`.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function, which handles an asynchronous function first *before* [`.then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) is called.

```
$.when($("select#category").val(category).change()).then(function() {
  $("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
});
```

Here below is a small example using those two functions. I have added a `console.log` function to the select change event handlers so that you can follow what happens.

```js
$("select#category").on('change', function() {
  console.log('[on change] category changed');
  $("select#subcategory").show();
});

$("select#subcategory").on('change', function() {
  console.log('[on change] subcategory changed');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize defaults
    var category = 1;
    var subcategory = 2;
    if (category && subcategory) {
        $.when($("select#category").val(category).change()).then(function() {
            console.log('[then] activating subcategory');
            $("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
        });
    }
});
```

```css
select#subcategory {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category">
 <option>...</option>
 <option value="1">value 1</option>
 <option value="2">value 2</option>
</select>
 
 <select id="subcategory">
   <option value="1">subvalue 1</option>
   <option value="2">subvalue 2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
},300);
```

maybe this? 
Wait 300 ms till make other change. I guess its enough to have a first one done :)

Comment: this works! but it is fundamentally incorrect. Usually I code Python and guessing is not really accepted there...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select#category").on("load",function(){
    $("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
});
```

Maybe this will work if I got your problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can listen for event `onChnage`

```
$("select#category").on("change",function(){
    $("select#subcategory").val(subcategory).change();
});
```

also instead of `$("select#category").val(category).change();`
try 
`$("select#category").val(category).trigger('change');`

Comment: the onChange event already runs before the second select-input is ready; this works only with the time out as suggested by @DanielWaw